# Central Grand Dispatcher: Run the same method in different queues/blocks

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Why does my code crashes?

```
    dispatch_async(queue_A, ^{
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [self logInfo:@"queue_A"];
        [pool release];        
    }
});

dispatch_async(queue_B, ^{
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [self logInfo:@"queue_B"];
        [pool release];        
    }
});
```

Comment: When I call this piiece of code about 5 times.(one by one)

Comment: One more question: if piece of code which is synchronized/locked by another queue other queue will run. What will happen? Crash ot queue will wait for some period of time?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and error message you see when the application crashes.

Comment: Why are you mixing GCD and @synchronized?

Comment: To avoid calling the same method (logInfo:) in both queues at the same time. Because it will crash. Correct?

Comment: If you want `logInfo:` to be thread safe, you should make it thread safe, rather than creating your own ad hoc means of calling methods. You also don't need to manage your own autorelease pools, GCD will do that for you. Since GCD is a C API, probably the most relevant question is: what checks do you have in place to ensure you've initialised queue_A and queue_B correctly?

Comment: Tommy, I didn't understand your question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off avoiding using `@syncronized` inside `dispatch_async`, as suggested in the comments. If it's not safe to call `[self logInfo:...]` then you might want to either:

1. Use a dispatch group to make sure multiple `dispatch_async()` calls to a resource don't crash your app. Mike Ash has a [good write-up of this technique](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-04-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-ii-multi-core-performance.html). Check out his examples.
2. Use a dispatch semaphore to force separate calls to wait for each other to complete. See the manpage for more.

I'm not sure what logInfo does in this context so you may be able to rewrite that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.

> Access to UI has to be via main queue ONLY